# Simple way of selecting uniq results in activercord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, request

```
irb(main):070:0> Moderation::Report.all.where(reportable_type: 'Message')
  Moderation::Report Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "reports".* FROM "reports" WHERE "reports"."reportable_type" = 'Message'
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Moderation::Report id: 1, reason: "Insults", status: "Pending", reportable_id: 1, reportable_type: "Message", user_id: 1, ban_id: nil, created_at: "2014-02-05 11:12:29", updated_at: "2014-02-05 11:23:03">, #<Moderation::Report id: 2, reason: "spam", status: "pending", reportable_id: 1, reportable_type: "Message", user_id: nil, ban_id: nil, created_at: "2014-02-05 11:40:45", updated_at: "2014-02-05 11:40:45">]>
```

I want only one field of each different reportable_id for this query.
And when there are multiple same reportable_id, it should only return one of them.

So, this request should return only one field instead of two.

I tried `.uniq.by(:reportable_id)`, but it doesn't exist anymore on Rails 4.
and `.select("DISTINCT(reportable_id)")` only select the reportable_id field

But after, I noticed that even if it would work, it wouldn't do what I'd like it to do

Do you have a solution?

Comment: which field you want to select with reportable_id ?

Comment: @sunil , I want to select every field of Report

Comment: .uniq is an array method.  Does it work if you swap them round, like `.by(:reportable_id).uniq` ?

Comment: actually, can't you just do a find(:first) instead of a find(:all), if you only want one result back?

Comment: @MaxWilliams Sunil just found what I wanted thanks anyways ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 Moderation::Report.group(:reportable_id)
```

It will give you only one record for each reporatble_id uniquely.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks I already tried that an hour ago, but as I had only two fields, and got only one result I thought that I couldn't iterate through it.
But thanks to you I just noticed that it is iterable ;)